# Primefaces 5.2 captcha component renders API 1.0 captcha

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, recaptcha

I am using Primefaces 5.2 and when i use the captcha component, it renders the old API 1.0 captcha. If you look at Primefaces 5.2 showcase it renders the latest API 2.0 captcha. What could be the problem?

Comment: Which 5.2 showcase exactly are you referring to? Currently, the [main showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/) doesn't use PrimeFaces 5.2. It's using PrimeFaces 5.2.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PrimeFaces latest community edition uses the **5.2** (i.e 5.2.0) version which implements the old captcha system from Google.

However, reCAPTCHA 2.0 has been introduced in **5.2.9** so you will have to wait for the next PrimeFaces 5.3 community edition (which is going to be released in "[early fall](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3580)" or in "[mid-septembre](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3491) 2015") or build and compile sources from the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces) by yourself if you cannot wait.

**Note** (edited following Kukeltje's comment): PrimeFaces' version of the showcase is usually updated when there are new components or major improvements. Current showcase version is **5.2.10** bringing the new *signature* component.

**See also**:
https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/54

Comment: @Kukeltje Good catch. Updated my side note.